# Why less leverage is allowed for cryptocurrency Spot trading?

Tags: trading, cryptocurrency, futures, leverage

I realized brokers and exchanges allow high leverage for Futures, Options and Forex listings but not so much for spot listings.

For example in Kraken Futures you can get 50x leverage for BTC-Perpetual, but for plain BTC maximum you can get is 5x. Some other Crypto exchanges don't even allow any leverage for spots.

What is the reason behind this?